# Pacemaker on a single-node RHEL-6 system

Tags: pacemaker

I am running pacemaker(1.x) and corosync on a single node system. I need it to configure in a way that if any resource does not start i.e. it has reached its **maximum threshold** then the pacemaker should stop all other resources as well.

For reference, my **configuration file** looks like this:

node Node1 \

```
    attributes maintenance=off
```

primitive alert_gen failoverscript \

```
    op start interval=0s timeout=20 \
    op stop interval=0s timeout=20 \
    op monitor interval=30s on-fail=restart \
    meta target-role=Started is-managed=true
```

primitive mon_RRDCache lsb:rrdcached \

```
    op monitor interval=30 timeout=60 \
    op start interval=0 timeout=60 \
    op stop interval=0 timeout=60 \
    meta is-managed=true on-fail=standby migration-threshold=2 failure-timeout=60
```

property cib-bootstrap-options: \

```
    dc-version="1.1.12-1.1.12+git20140723.483f48a" \
    cluster-infrastructure="classic openais (with plugin)" \
    last-lrm-refresh=1461912140 \
    no-quorum-policy=ignore \
    expected-quorum-votes=1 \
    start-failure-is-fatal=false \
    stonith-enabled=false
```

I have tried it using **on-fail=standby** but it only stops **mon_RRDCache** monitoring.
But I want that the pacemaker should stop all resources.